# how to make sure google maps iOS SDK not using private API?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

Google maps SDK for iOS is released by google recently and I am planning to integrate that in my iphone app. But I want to make sure that google not using any private API in their API to avoid rejection by apple.

is there any way or place where i can confirm that Google Maps iOS SDK not using private API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, but I don't think you need to worry (that) much. Apple's reject pattern is very arbitrary but if you're using a library that says Google on it you are likely safe. Still you'll never know until you try.

Comment: True.But It's quiet surprising to know that Google or Apple never mention about it anywhere. I am just hoping they do have it somewhere, but I am not able to find it, but there must be someone who have seen it and m counting on that.

Comment: After lot of googling we concluded that there is no private API usage by Google Maps SDK which can be the reason for rejection!!!